# Django 'bool' object is not iterable on model save

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update my model, so when a BooleanField is checked via the admin, it updates all the other rows to be reset to False (0). But when I keep doing this it just returns the following TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Here is my model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telephone       = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    email           = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    primary_contact = models.BooleanField('Primary Contact')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def make_primary(self):
        Contact.objects.filter(id!=self.id).update(primary_contact=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.primary_contact == True):
            self.make_primary()
        super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm Trying to update my rows during save() using a custom method called make_primary(). It feels like there is something super simple and obvious that I need to do. I'm new to Django, so it's a bit of a learning curve.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

As requested here is my traceback / error below. Also, I updated my code to use exclude instead and the error has changed to: 'long' object is not iterable

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/contact/contact/1/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tinymce',
 'adminsortable',
 'taggit',
 'contact')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/adminsortable/admin.py" in change_view
  231.             form_url='', extra_context=extra_context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1519.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1467.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1078.         obj.save()
File "/Users/[hidden]/Sites/[hidden]/contact/models.py" in save
  37.           self.make_primary()
File "/Users/[hidden]/Sites/[hidden]/contact/models.py" in make_primary
  28.       for oc in other_contacts:

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/contact/contact/1/
Exception Value: 'long' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please can you post the full traceback? Note that `filter(id!=self.id)` is not valid. You need to do `exclude(id=self.id)` instead. You can also simplify the first line of the save method to `if self.primary_contact:`, you don't need to compare to `True` in Python.

Comment: I've added the full traceback to my original post.

Comment: You have not shown the line `for oc in other_contacts:` which is failing.

Comment: ah that was a bit of old code I forgot to comment out. However, I removed it an it's now working! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is invalid:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id!=self.id)
```

When you do `id!=self.id`, the expression evaluates to `False`, so it's the same as doing `filter(False)`. That's the bool object that is 'not iterable' in your traceback message, it doesn't actually have anything to do with your `BooleanField`.

When you do `filter(id=self.id)`, you are passing a keyword argument to the `filter` method. Django doesn't have a way to do not equal as a keyword argument in a filter. You can use [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) instead.

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(id=self.id)
```

Comment: I've done that, but now i get a different error: 'long' object is not iterable

Comment: as mentioned above it was a piece of code I forgot to comment out. By updating my query to use exclude it appears to have fixed my problem. Thanks.